# Cannot open gnome-terminal preferences window

Tags: command-line, unity, upgrade, 15.04, gnome-terminal

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04, I can no longer access gnome-terminal preferences from `edit > profile preferences.`

Things I have tried to no avail:

- Switching to another profile using `terminal > profile > Default`
- Editing the default profile and even editing a newly created one in `edit > profiles`
- Resetting gnome-terminal preferences using `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/gnome-terminal`
  and
  `rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal`
- I have also monitored `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/dmesg` with `tail -f`

Any help is greatly welcome and very appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

It turns out my gnome-terminal was somehow outdated, even after running `apt-get upgrade` several times. I found this out by running `apt search gnome-terminal`, which gave me the following output:

`$ apt search gnome-terminal
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
gnome-terminal/vivid 3.14.2-0ubuntu3 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.6.2-0ubuntu1]
  GNOME terminal emulator application`

So I followed with `apt-get install gnome-terminal` which also updated its dependencies. I also still have a lot of outdated packages, I hope I'll be able to figure those ones out as a simple `apt-get upgrade` does not help there.